# Select2: Add and select manual values when using ajax data source

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want to achieve following scenario with select2(4.0.0) and jquery(2.1.4):

- I have a select box which takes data from external source (end point on java application server)
- User can either pick one of the returned values or come up with his own value
- Now when user submits the form and the validation on the server side fails I would like to display the form with all the values provided previously by the user, therefore select box should have the value send to the server.

To achieve that

- I use *ajax* from select to query data from the server
- I use *createTag* to allow user to create his own values
- I wanted to use *initSelection* to prefill selectbox with a value previously added by user.

My code looks like this:

```js
$("select[name='serie']").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "http://javaendpoit/serie/filter",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            name: params.term,
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
          return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
              return {
                text: item.name,
                name: item.name,
                id: item.name
              }
            })
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      templateResult: formatRepo,
      templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
      tags: true,
      createTag: function (tag) {
        return {
          id: tag.term,
          text: tag.term,
          name: tag.term,
          isNew : true
        };
      },
      /* below part is rendered by jsp so that it has the value from previous form submission; if it is initial form render the below part is not included */
      initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            callback({id:"Name",name:"Name","text":"Name"});
      }   
    });

 function formatRepo (serie) {
        if (serie.loading) return serie.text;
        var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
        '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
        '<div class="clearfix">' +
        '<div class="col-xs-12">' + serie.name + '</div>' +
        '</div>';
        markup += '</div></div>';
        return markup;
  }

  function formatRepoSelection (serie) {
    return serie.name;
  }
```

This works just fine. Meaning that after the submission I can see value Name in the select box and it's the selected value. Nevertheless, if I try to submit this form again, the value is missing in the request.

As suggested in the number of topics here I added following line (see last line).

```js
  /* [...] */
  initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        callback({id:"Name",name:"Name","text":"Name"});
  }   
}).select2("val","Name");
```

But after adding this the value *Name* is not even visible in the select2 box.

I have been trying to fix it for few hours now, but somehow cannot find the right solution. I bet I am missing some basic stuff. Plese help!

--- [EDIT]

After adding *data* I am able to see the value Name even when setting the value with *val* nevertheless if I resubmit the form this value is still not present in the request.

```js
.select2('data',{id:"Name",name:"Name","text":"Name"})
.select2('val', "Name")
```

--- [EDIT 2]

In html I use *select* to create this element.

```
<select class="form-control" name="serie"></select>
```

Comment: [This mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/select2/Vr4ga8KeojQ/9sOIYa3LR5AJ) might help give you some pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Also, in Select2 4.0.0 the `select2('data')` method is not writable and will trigger a warning if you set `debug: true` when initializing Select2.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I saw this thread before, but it had no responses until few our ago. Also I have checked the solutions proposed there (links to stackoverflow) but with no help. Nevertheless, I will try to re run the examples showed there during the weekend, maybe I have missed something.
Regarding select2('data'), that explains why values specified there were not taken into account.

Comment: Hi Kevin! I was able to solve the issue without using initSelection as you suggested in the mailing list thread. Thank you!

Comment: The mailing list doesn't provide any solution to init locale data and then load data from ajax source. Initial html <option> aren't showing in the select2 dropdown. Any solutions ?

Comment: Hi @singe3 . Not sure if this is the best solution but I guess you could always implement processResults that processes ajax response to return not only values coming from ajax call but as well some initial values (obtained either by parsing option tags or hardcoded in the javascript code itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin I was able to solve the puzzle. So ultimately I have given up on using initSelection. Instead I just filled select tag with options that should be selected.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="author" name="author" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="name" selected="selected">name</option>
</select>
```

Removed initSelection from select2 definition

```
$("select[name='author']").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "http://javaendpoit/serie/filter",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                name: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        name: item.name,
                        id: item.name
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (tag) {
        return {
            id: tag.term,
            text: tag.term,
            name: tag.term,
            isNew: true
        };
    }
});
```

And changed formatRepoSelection to work with values without *name* attribute.

```
function formatRepoSelection(serie) {
    if (serie.name === undefined) {
        return serie.text;
    } else {
        return serie.name;
    }
}
```

I guess I could not use *name* attribute in the *formatRepo* and could remove the if clause for *formatRepoSelection*. But this is just a minor fix.

Answer (score 3):

I manage to do that with select2 version 4.0.2 like this :

```
$("select[name='serie']").data('select2')
    .dataAdapter.select({
        id:"Name",
        name:"Name",
        "text":"Name"
    });
```